# Web API No type was found that matches the controller named

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, routes

I see that this error gets asked a lot, but so far no luck. I have a .Net 4 (VS2010) web SITE project. I have a Web API project as a seperate project, in the same solution. I can call the Web API from web pages on my local machine, no problem. I push the whole thing to production and web api calls fail with:

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://khdecisiontool.ecitystage.net/api/slider/69'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'slider'."}
```

To register everything I do this in Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This enables api controllers in a separate class library
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new AssembliesResolver());
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

    var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter); 

    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

}
```

And the my API route is like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        ).RouteHandler = new ECityHttpControllerRouteHandler();
```

This is placed AFTER my web forms routes.

**EDIT**

Here is the controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Api controller for sliders
/// </summary>
[Authorize]
public class SliderController : ApiController
{
    SliderService context = new SliderService();

    // GET api/slider
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of all sliders as slider dtos
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<SliderDto> Get()
    {
        var sliderList = new List<SliderDto>();
        var sliders = context.GetSliders();
        foreach (var slider in sliders)
        {
            var sliderDto = new SliderDto
            {
                ID = slider.ID,
                PersonID = slider.PersonID,
                ContentPageID = slider.ContentPageID,
                StartValue = slider.StartValue,
                EndValue = slider.EndValue,
                Date = slider.Date.ToLongDateString() + slider.Date.ToLongTimeString()
            };
            sliderList.Add(sliderDto);
        }
        return sliderList.ToList();
    }

    // GET api/slider/5
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a single slider as sliderDto
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public SliderDto Get(int id)
    {
        var slider = context.GetSlider(id);
        if (slider != null)
        {
            var sliderDto = new SliderDto
            {
                ID = slider.ID,
                PersonID = slider.PersonID,
                ContentPageID = slider.ContentPageID,
                StartValue = slider.StartValue,
                EndValue = slider.EndValue,
                Date = slider.Date.ToLongDateString() + slider.Date.ToLongTimeString()
            };
            return sliderDto;
        }
        return new SliderDto { StartValue = 0, EndValue = 0 };            
    }

    // POST api/slider
    /// <summary>
    /// Insert a slider
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sliderDto">The slider Dto</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(SliderDto sliderDto)
    {
        var slider = new Slider
        {
            ID = sliderDto.ID,
            PersonID = sliderDto.PersonID,
            ContentPageID = sliderDto.ContentPageID,
            StartValue = sliderDto.StartValue,
            EndValue = sliderDto.EndValue,
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };
        var id = context.AddSlider(slider);
        var item = context.GetSlider(id);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Slider>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

        string uri = Url.Link("Default", new { id = id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }

    // PUT api/slider/5
    /// <summary>
    /// Update a slider using the SliderDto
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="sliderDto"></param>
    public void Put(int id, SliderDto sliderDto)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = context.GetSlider(id);
            data.ID = sliderDto.ID;
            data.PersonID = sliderDto.PersonID;
            Nullable<int> contentId = null;
            if (sliderDto.ContentPageID.HasValue && sliderDto.ContentPageID.Value != 0)
                contentId = sliderDto.ContentPageID.Value;
            data.ContentPageID = contentId;
            data.StartValue = sliderDto.StartValue;
            data.EndValue = sliderDto.EndValue;
            data.Date = DateTime.Now;                
            context.UpdateSlider(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }

    // DELETE api/slider/5
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete a slider
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var item = context.GetSlider(id);
        if (item == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        context.DeleteSlider(item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the assembly resolver:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for AssembliesResolver
/// </summary>
public class AssembliesResolver : System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        ICollection<Assembly> baseAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies);        

        var controllersAssembly = Assembly.Load("MyAssemblyName");
        baseAssemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);
        return assemblies;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add your controller definition ?

Comment: I suspect the issue is with your custom assemblies resolver...can you share how it looks like?